# What is logging level in tensorflow and why people used it in notebooks?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In many collab and jupyter notebooks I see people use these lines like:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

what is the use of it? I didn't understand much from the documentation

Comment: Please do not write in all-bold (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf_logging` module is located here: [`tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py). As you can see from the source code, `tensorflow` uses the standard python's `logging` module, here:

```
import logging as _logging
```

Without going in further detail, do consult python's standard logging documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging). With this you will be well equipped to understand what is going on in the tensorflow logging implementation. In short, the line above configures the logging to print/write to file (depending on how is it configured) `error` messages, and ignore `warning`, `info`, and `debug` messages (see info about log levels [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#levels)).